# what do you call a person who does not like to share information?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Is there any word for a person who does not like to share information?

Comment: What, you mean like all the people who **don’t** answer this question? :)

Comment: You will have to add more context to the question. It's overly broad right now. Person can be *secretive* or *private* for a number of reasons and in number of situations. Putting that secrecy in right context can be helpful in finding you the right word.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the following words are not exactly what you are asking for, but many of them are on-point.  Some of them would work in a sentence that included the word *information*, such as "He was selfish, even with information that could be helpful to the group."  Or, "He was very retiring and was reluctant to share his knowledge."  And so on.

You could use any of the following words:  secretive, taciturn, silent, uncommunicative, selfish, closelipped, tightlipped, close-mouthed, untalkative, reticent, mute, introverted, shy, bashful, retiring, timid, distrustful, wary, suspicious, reluctant, controlled, disinclined, loath, averse, taciturn, or silent.

Comment: I regard the visually-striking formatting of that list as a perfect achievement on your part – it's perfectly awful!  Commas between words in a list often's sufficient.

Comment: @jwpat7:  Point taken.  It was two in the morning, and perhaps I wasn't thinking clearly.  My bad.